# How to work with Joomla database object?

Tags: object, joomla

I have a this in local server(USBWEBSERVER):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dbemployeekpw WHERE username LIKE '$param%'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $formality = $myrow["formality"];
```

But in Joomla this doesn't work, how can I change it for a Joomla database object?

This is the way to I Connect to the Joomla DB and works fine in other scrips:

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query  = "SELECT  `email` FROM  `brg4w_users`";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObjectList();
    $email  = $result[0];
    echo $email->email
```

So I suppose in this script will be something like this(I'm not sure):

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dbemployeekpw WHERE username = 'camilo.uribe@kantarworldpanel.com'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadAssocList();
```

foreach ($results as $myrow)

{ echo $myrow->fullname; }

But doesn't work, so the question is, how can I made this in Joomla languaje:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $formality = $myrow["formality"];
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should have a read of the [Joomla Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase) for database queries. It gives some good information and examples

Your question will look something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select('*');
->from($db->quoteName('dbemployeekpw'))
->where($db->quoteName('username') .'='. $db->quote('camilo.uribe@kantarworldpanel.com'));

$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
     $result->formality;
}
```

If your database table is part of a Joomla extension, then replace `dbemployeekpw` with `#__dbemployeekpw`.

Just make sure you **never** use `mysql_*` for your database queries. Also note that I haven't tested this query, so let me know if it works or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: May want `$db->loadAssocList()` instead of `loadObjectList()` if you want to get an array of arrays back instead of an array of objects.

Comment: Hey, doesn't work :( 
I edit the post with more informacion, I hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: @CamiloUribe - I have updated my answer with some code changes. Try again. If it doesn't work, please edit your question and only provide the code you have so far and also include the database columns for the table.